# how to validate html5 form inputs on keyup?

Tags: html, validation

Html5 validations only looking for user's input when user press submit button. It is possible to validate user input while user typing ? is this possible ??

For example i have an input "" this is validating only when user click submit.

I want to validate while user typing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be of some help.

http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/

http://jsfiddle.net/ianoxley/VY8KU/ - this will change the css style while typing the wrong input.

```
input:invalid,
input:out-of-range {
    border-color:hsl(0, 50%, 50%);
    background:hsl(0, 50%, 90%);
}
```

Comment: yes i am using this css3 pseudo selectors, i just want to know weather it is possible to give error messages or hints also while user typing. Since it is only displaying that "this field is required" when user click submit.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by adding an event listener to the form input field on the `input` event using the HTML5 validation function `setCustomValidity` in the following way:

```
yearInpEl.addEventListener("input", function () { 
  yearInpEl.setCustomValidity( Book.checkYear( yearInpEl.value).message);
});
```

Here `yearInpEl`is the object reference to the input field element, and `checkYear` is a user-defined validation function for the attribute `year` of a model class `Book`.

The HTML5 validation function `setCustomValidity` expects an empty string as an argument for confirming successful validation, or otherwise a validation error message to be displayed.

For more about HTML5 form validation, see [this tutorial](https://oxygen.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/IT/JsFrontendApp/simple-tutorial.html).